# Modifier clause question?

Tags: modifiers

In the following sentence, what parts are incorrect or ungrammatical?  (GMAT related)

> The new “e-waste” salvage company collects electronic waste items, such as old cellular telephones and broken personal music players, discarding them as trash, to transport them to state facilities for recycling.

What does "discarding items as trash" refer back to, the salvage company or music players? Are there rules that apply here?

Answer (score 1):

From the context, I guess the intended meaning of 'discard' here is 'to remove, or to preserve', which is exactly the opposite of its standard meaning, and makes the sentence confusing.

I'd suggest 'recovering them from X' (where X could be 'landfill' or 'waste').

I'd also change 'to transport' to 'and transports' for clarity, as 'collects...to transport' implies that the main reason they collect them is to transport them, which, again, doesn't fit the intended meaning, which is 'collects...to recycle'.